# not able to change array item with findIndex

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to change a value from an array. I have been researching and the code doesn't seem to work. I have multiple

```js
Array = [{
val1: "1",  //these are actually lots of random numbers but im not gonna go though all that code 
val2: "2",
nameval: "name",
val4: "3"
},{
val1: "4",
val2: "5",
nameval: "name",
val4: "6"}]


function updateName(e) {
    let pos = Array.findIndex(i => i.val1 === e.id ); 
    if (Array[pos]) {
            Array[pos][nameval] = "work";
        } else {
            Array[pos] = {
                nameval: "work",
            };
        }
        console.log(Array)
        console.log("this should be 1 but it is: " + Array.findIndex(i => i.val1 === e.id))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input onchange="updateName(this)" class="first-class" id ="4" >
</label>
```

I know of at least one problem which is at the beginning of this code `Array.findIndex(i => i.val1`. That returns -1 which means that it failed.

Here are some of the links I use:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indexof-method-in-an-object-array-in-javascript/

I was also getting an error and this code supposedly fixed it: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-cannot-set-property-of-undefined

Comment: Can you update the code to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  Also, naming your variable `Array` is probably [a very bad idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and could very well be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Yeah i can update it. All the names are the same as i am using in mu project. I named them differently so that it makes sence. There is also more html and css but it isnt relevant

Comment: @David It is now runnable.

Comment: The next step is some debugging.  First, again, don't name your variable `Array`.  That's only going to cause problems.  Second, what do you expect `e.id` to be and why?  `e` is a reference to `this` from the HTML element, and that element has no `id`. You can use your browser's debugger to step through the function line by line as it executes and observe the runtime values of your variables. Failing that, you can also litter it with `console.log` statements to observe the runtime values. Do this step by step in your logic and identify the specific operation which isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: Oops. I mean that all the names are not the same as i am using in my project. I think i know the problem now. As you mentioned, there is no id. For some reason I allways thought the numbers were the id. This is most likely the problem. I will come back later and confirm if that is true. Thanks @David

Comment: I actually have an id in my original project but I didn't put it in the code. fixing it now

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle two cases:

1. object is found

If `.findIndex()` returns a number other than -1, then update the element

2. object is not found

`.findIndex()` returns -1. Then take action. e.g. insert a new object, do nothing, return error

```js
const dataArray = [{
    val1: "1",  //these are actually lots of random numbers but im not gonna go though all that code 
    val2: "2",
    nameval: "name",
    val4: "3"
  },{
    val1: "4",
    val2: "5",
    nameval: "name",
    val4: "6"
  }
]


function updateName(search) {
    let pos = dataArray.findIndex(i => i.val1 === search.id ); 
    if (pos > -1) {
        // found, so update
        dataArray[pos].nameval = search.new_value;
    } else {
        // not found, take action
        // option 1)
        //   add a new entry with default data:
        dataArray.push({
            val1: search.id,
            val2: "2",
            nameval: search.new_value,
            val4: "4"
        });
        // // option 2)
        // //   add a new entry with the data passed in search
        // dataArray.push({
        //     val1: search.id,
        //     val2: search.val2,
        //     nameval: search.new_value,
        //     val4: "4"
        // });
        
        // option 3)
        // take no action
    }
    console.log(dataArray)
    console.log("id: "+search.id+" now index is " + dataArray.findIndex(i => i.val1 === search.id))
}

updateName({id:"1", new_value: "work"})
updateName({id:"4", new_value: "developer"})
updateName({id:"878", new_value: "freelancer"})
```